# How can I remove all text after a specific substring from a column value?

Tags: mysql

I have a column table with rows like this:

```
Rabbit</h1> is Running
Dogs</h1> are Swimming
```

I'd like to modify this to:

```
Rabbit
Dog
```

Specifically, I'd like to remove the `</h1>` and all following text.

How can I do this?

Comment: Read up on substring_index (and mysq string functions generally) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index Try it and come back explaining why this doesn't work for you if appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by N left characters? Your examples do not have the same amount of characters removed. Do all your rows have `</h1>` and you want to remove it and any following text?

Comment: Yes all rows have <h1> and I want to remove it and any following text

Comment: Then yes, definitely check P.Salmon's link above :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please [don't include tags in your title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) -- that's what the tags field is for. :)  (I've done an edit to remove them in this case, as well as make the title closer to your goal, based on the comment).